# cPanel sent email resulting as SPAM in Google and Outlook

Tags: cpanel, spam, exim

I've been struggling for quite some time with a specific email server setup based on a cPanel. For some reason emails sent out from this specific server are being marked as spam and delivered to spam/junk folders of Gmail and Outlook. Can somebody with bigger experience please have a look at my current configurations and maybe point out any flaws in the setup or give a hint as to what to look for?

```
IP addresses at disposal: x.x.x.127/27
cPanel installed on: x.x.x.99
Domains added to WHM on x.x.x.99-105
In order not to disclose the domain names, I won't be able to provide exact domain names, sorry.
```

Emails are being marked as spam when sending from x.x.x.99-105 by either web interface and using email clients.

SPF, DKIM, MX, PTR entries are valid. 
Domains and IP addresses is not within blacklist check that mxtoolbox.com website offers.

```
Mail-tester.com results: 8.1/10, main points off have gone from PYZOR_CHECK (-1.985). The message it provides is:
Similar message reported on Pyzor (http://pyzor.org)
Please test a real content, test Newsletters will always be flagged by Pyzor
Adjust your message or request whitelisting (http://public.pyzor.org/whitelist/)
```

Microsoft SNDS does not provide reasons for being marked as spam from what I can see. 
Microsoft support does not provide information on how to proceed with issue fixing. 
Google Postmaster does not provide reasons for being marked as spam from what I can see. 
Google support does not reply on how to proceed with issue fixing.

Software versions:

```
/etc/redhat-release:CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core)
/usr/local/cpanel/version:11.58.0.28
/var/cpanel/envtype:standard
CPANEL=release
Server version: Apache/2.4.18 (Unix)
Server built: Jun 10 2016 08:13:27
Cpanel::Easy::Apache v3.32.14 rev9999
PHP 5.5.36 (cli) (built: Jun 10 2016 08:15:50)
Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies
mysql Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.31, for Linux (x86_64) using EditLine wrapper
```

I've completely lost my mind, discovering this... Outlook.com support only sent us a link to the terms and conditions of their service. Google did not respond to a support query at all. I would be glad for any clue on where to search for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Probably MX records for those domains are not pointing to the main server IP.

This is a common reason for mail being blocked or being marked as spam for most servers.

Check your dns zones for the problematic domains.

**If you find :**

> domain.com. IN MX domain.com.

**change it to:**

> domain.com IN MX mail.domain.com.

**AND change the record for mail(domain2.com) this way:**

> mail.domain.com IN A yourmainserverIPhere

Finally add your main server IP to your SPF records. Wait for a while before checking mail, because DNS changes need a time to be propagated.

Hope this helps.

***Note :***

Also go through the following link for detailed information

[How to Keep your Email out of the Spam Folder](https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/CKB/How+to+Keep+your+Email+out+of+the+Spam+Folder)